# nuxt build (SPA) generetes ./nuxt/dist/**

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Whenever I run

```
$ npm run build
```

on Nuxt SPA mode it generates a *./dist* folder and **./nuxt/dist** folder.

What's the use of **./nuxt/dist**?

[./nuxt/dist folder sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHUi2.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dist folder contains html and js files then you can use it to deploy to server and run as statics site.

Comment: Is this for **/dist** folder or **./nuxt/dist**?

Comment: It base on your nuxt config, but by default, it is .nuxt
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-builddir

Comment: Ohhh I see, I've read that the */dist* folder is the static version. It's just weird that `$ npm run build` generates this as well. Thank you for your help BTW!

Comment: So if Nuxt @ v2.15.8
Environment: production
Rendering: server-side
Target: server
Then NUXT serves the assets from 
html/.nuxt/dist/ not from html/dist/_nuxt/ or html/static or html/assets?
I can see my file names are the same in html/.nuxt/dist/ as all 404 files in crome dev (example.com/_nuxt/example.js), that's why I'm confused. I now ran /nuxt start --port 3003 but normally pm2 start -- --port 3003. Same issue in both: all assets get 404.

Comment: To clarify: I only get issues with missing files on the live Ubuntu 20.04 NGINX server, not locally in Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt.js lets you upload your dist files to your CDN for maximum performances, simply set the publicPath to your CDN.

```
export default {
  build: {
    publicPath: 'https://cdn.nuxtjs.org'
  }
}
```

Then, when launching nuxt build, upload the content of .nuxt/dist/client directory to your CDN.

Ref: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/

Comment: I set publicPath: 'https://example.com/cdn', and copied the content in /var/www/example.com/html/.nuxt/dist/client to /var/www/example.com/html/cdn but when I check the server error.log it says: " "/var/www/example.com/html/.nuxt/dist/cdn/85451fa.js" failed (2: No such file...." I even now copied the same files to /var/www/example.com/html/.nuxt/dist/cdn but even after that I get 404 on all assets. I even did  sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/example.com/html/cdn In Chrome it's correct URL https://example.com/cdn/85451fa.js

Answer (score 0):

The contents in the nuxt/dist folder are what is going to be served up when you are in production. It contains an optimized code to be served to your users.

Answer (score -1):

.nuxt/dist is for server side rendering it will be use when you run npm run start on your server and it will start listening on localhost:3000